# Products Security in Partner Community

Tags: security, opportunity-lineitem, partner-communities, product, global-search

We are currently working with Products and Pricebooks in Partner Community. The security side of it is still an idea in Salesforce but is there anyway we could restrict the Products visibility for Partners who are not supposed to view them?

Their Pricebook visibility is limited but they could still view Products of other Partners through Global Search. How do we restrict them from viewing? Currently we are thinking of overriding the branding header of Partner portal to limit visibility of the search box. Would there be a better solution for this?

**Scenario:**

Say we have Products(Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4, Prod5, Prod6).

Consider we have 2 Partners PartnerA and PartnerB.
In this *PartnerA* need to see only (Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4)
for *PartnerB* need to see only (Prod1, Prod2, Prod5, Prod6).

**PartnerA should not see (Prod5, Prod6)**

**PartnerB should not see (Prod3, Prod4)**

We tried this by creating 2 Pricebook(Pricebook1 and Pricebook2) for each Partners.

1. PartnerA has only access to Pricebook1.
2. PartnerB has only access to Pricebook2.

**OWD setting:**

Pricebook: **No Access**

After this, PartnerA can only see the product associated with Pricebook1 (Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4) in OpportunityLineItem. 
But the product (Prod5, Prod6) is still visible in **Global search**.

Is there any way to restrict these Product from Global Search or any workaround?